# Is my ssd realy broken, or is this still fixable?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd

my first sdd, an OCZ Vertex 3, does not work anymore. It is like 'not found' in the bios while booting. However, I tried a bit more. I attached it to my PC using a SATA-to-USB3 cable/adapter.

### dmesg output

Here's what dmesg says:

```
# USB device detected
[995674.616272] usb 2-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[995674.739558] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0731
[995674.739561] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[995674.739564] usb 2-1.4: Product: USB Storage
[995674.739566] usb 2-1.4: SerialNumber: 0000000000000033

# this is where the device gets detected
[995674.740213] usb-storage 2-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[995674.740451] scsi host9: usb-storage 2-1.4:1.0
[995676.205066] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB3/SATA Bridge 9100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[995676.205568] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[995676.208525] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[995676.208529] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] 0-byte physical blocks
[995676.210177] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[995676.211910] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] Asking for cache data failed
[995676.211916] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[995676.219509] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
```

See the size? It should be more like 60 GB (not GiB), not just 0 bytes.

### First try: Gparted

Starting gparted, it said "device not found" using /dev/sdd as an argument.

Then I started gparted without arguments => device not listed.

### 2nd try: dd.

Didn't go that well either.

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=1M
dd: error writing '/dev/sdd': No space left on device
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0,00073185 s, 0,0 kB/s
```

## 3rd try: testdisk

Not detected.

## 4th try: smart

So I thought: the disk does get detected, but 0 bytes means all sectors are broken? Perhaps smart will tell me.

Well, no.

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdd
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-20-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error no medium present

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.

$ sudo smartctl -a -T permissive /dev/sdd 
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-20-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error no medium present

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     [No Information Found]
Serial Number:    [No Information Found]
Firmware Version: [No Information Found]
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   [No Information Found]
Local Time is:    Fri May 25 20:53:53 2018 CEST
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show if SMART supported.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't show if SMART is enabled.
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.

$ sudo smartctl -a -T verypermissive /dev/sdd 
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-20-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error no medium present

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     [No Information Found]
Serial Number:    [No Information Found]
Firmware Version: [No Information Found]
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   [No Information Found]
Local Time is:    Fri May 25 20:54:02 2018 CEST
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show if SMART supported.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't show if SMART is enabled.
                  Checking to be sure by trying SMART RETURN STATUS command.
SMART support is: Unknown - Try option -s with argument 'on' to enable it.
Read SMART Data failed: scsi error no medium present

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status command failed: scsi error no medium present
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: UNKNOWN!
SMART Status, Attributes and Thresholds cannot be read.

Read SMART Error Log failed: scsi error no medium present

Read SMART Self-test Log failed: scsi error no medium present

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

So no luck either…

I'm out of options?
Put it in the bin or is this fixeable?

### update

I made sure it is not fixable anymore. I guess there was no way of fixing it anymore, so I took this option.

[image: It's dead, Jim]

Comment: Any ability to reflash the firmware on it? If not then probably garbage

Comment: I'll try that. Win10 VM is starting. Updating… will take some time. ;-)

Comment: @EricF firmware is not flashable. Those utilities won't even recognize any storage.

Comment: Just saw the updated version of this question when answering a comment made on my answer.  If others are thinking of physical destruction as a means of making partial data  unreadable to an adversary they should at minimum destroy each of the chips on the board - if the data is valuable enough, the chips can be resoldered and attempts made to read the data off them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SSD is really broken. Even if you can somehow get it working again it will most likely die again is short order.

When you plug the device in via USB it's recognising the existence of a mass storage device - but it sees it as having 0 bytes of storage capacity.

What you are seeing is a textbook SSD failure.

Comment: Probably the trick is not to get S.M.A.R.T. data once the device seems dead, but before. When running `smartd` (and the bridge is supporting it) you can get the historic data values logged via option `--attributelog=PREFIX`.